# How to append grouped series to excel sheet? Pandas, openpyxl

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I have a grouped series that looks something like this:

```
12/06/2019 Started        15
           Completed      5
12/10/2017 Started        21
           No Start Date  30
10/01/2018 Started        4
```

I want to export it to an excel file but can't seem to do so with openpyxl, the format of the series is difficult to append. I was able to get the series to append to a single cell with wraparound text, but I would like everything to be separated in cells.

Answer (score 0):

I would convert to a `pandas` dataframe and use `xlwings` library to export (push) it into an excel file.

here's how:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import xlwings as xw
    
s = pd.Series(["a", "b", "c"],name="columns")
dt = s.to_frame()

xw.Book(news_file).sheets['Sheet1'].range('A1').value = dt
```

File can either be closed or or open. Xlwings will open an Excel instance and print the data via COM into the file.